# java-construct Set from 2D Integer array and back Set to 2D Integer array

Tags: java

I have converted 2D Integer array[n][3] into LinkedHashSet (for removing duplicates in row) using following code.

```
  final Set<Set<Integer>> r = new LinkedHashSet<Set<Integer>>();
  for(Integer[] row:orderedpair3k) 
  r.add(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(row)));
```

How do I convert this back to a 2D array?

Comment: "pls code" is not the best way to ask if you want an answer...

Comment: "giveh me the codezzz immediately" would be the propper phrase to use

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson, also I'd replace "the" by "teh"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is homework...

Step 1: Create an array with the `size()` of the outter `Set`

Step 2: Loop through the `Sets` in the outter `Set`

Step 3: For each inner `Set` use `toArray(new Integer[0])` to get the inner array

Step 4: Assign the new inner array to the correct position of the outter array.

Comment: You should prefer `toArray(new Integer[set.size()])`. It avoids the creation of an unneeded empty array.

Comment: Hmmm.  I guess I sometimes prefer the alternative of having a `static final` empty array -- which can by definition never be modified -- and using that to avoid unnecessary allocation.

Comment: ya john sir i have tried according to homework but the code is generating run time exception so that i didn't get array element as individual plz check and provide your helpful comments

Comment: code is as follows:public void backToArray() 
 {   
      Integer[][] a = new Integer[r.size()][3]; 
      for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
      a[j]=r.toArray(new Integer[j]);
 }